# Trim Text Between Two Similar Identifiers C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring, trim

I have a string

```
string myString = "NotNeeded/ThisTextIsNeeded/NotNeeded";
```

I just need "**ThisTextIsNeeded**" and the starting and ending identifiers are same **"/"**. I can use Substring but for that I will need different identifiers. Can anyone please guide me how to do it using similar identifiers in C#.

**Edit:** The string cannot be necessarily "**NotNeeded/ThisTextIsNeeded/NotNeeded**". It can also be changed for example "**ABC/ThisTextIsNeeded/ABC**" or "**AAA/APPPP/ABC**". I just need any text that comes in between **/** and **/**.

Thanks

Comment: `String.Replace("NotNeeded", "")`?

Comment: What about splitting on `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- You can use `regex`**

```
string regexPattern = @"(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/)";
var match = Regex.Match("NotNeeded/ThisTextIsNeeded/NotNeeded", regexPattern);
```

**Output:** **ThisTextIsNeeded**

2- Or, `Split` `string` by using **"/"**

```
string text = "NotNeeded/ThisTextIsNeeded/NotNeeded";
string[] list = text.Split('/');
```

**Output:** `list[1]` will be -> **ThisTextIsNeeded**

Comment: where 2- is much faster than 1-